# How to Call Data structure from other classes

Tags: java, class, methods, data-structures, one-simulator

I want to call data structure from another classes but i find a problem here,
can you help me?

here the source code

The data structure from class SimBetWithFairRouting

```
public  Map<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> neighborsHistory;
```

and i will call it in this method from class NeighbourhoodSimilarity

```
private double countDirectSimilarity(double[][] matrixEgoNetwork, int index) {
    double sim=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixEgoNetwork.length; i++) {
//here the problem
        if (matrixEgoNetwork[i][0]==this.countAggrIntStrength(*i will call it in here*) && matrixEgoNetwork[i][index]==1) {
            sim++;

        }
    }

    return sim;

}
```

any way i can make this work without changing the map into static form?
clue : in the class SimBetWithFairRouting had replicate method,  can you help me?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing.. What did you to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the map, you have to import that class to the class where you write the method. And to access it without creating an instance you have to make it static.

```
private double countDirectSimilarity(double[][] matrixEgoNetwork, int index) {
    double sim=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixEgoNetwork.length; i++) {
            if (matrixEgoNetwork[i][0]==this.countAggrIntStrength(SimBetWithFairRouting.neighborsHistory) && matrixEgoNetwork[i][index]==1) {
            sim++;

        }
    }

    return sim;

}
```

Make your map static

```
public static Map<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> neighborsHistory;
```

Answer (score 0):

First import that package where your SimBetWithFairRouting class resides.
and then make that Map (neighborsHistory) as static.

and to access that map you can use

```
    SimBetWithFairRouting.neighborsHistory
```

which is (ClassName.MapName)

Comment: can i make it without static?, because i had method replicate in the  class SimBetWithFairRouting, isn't static is the same with replicate?

Comment: You have to make it static else you have to create object of that class for accessing that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Extending *SimBetWithFairRouting* class from *NeighbourhoodSimilarity* can also give you access to *neighborsHistory* (if *SimBetWithFairRouting* class is not final).